# Is there a way to make my foreground service run without stopping. It stops when phone cache is cleared by Cross(X) button in minimize window?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile, android-service

I have made a foreground service and it runs non-stop but stops only when the phone cache is cleared (Clicking on Cross(X) button in the Recent Apps window ). Is there a way I can run it non-stop even after clearing the recent apps? And yes, there are other applications which run non-stop in this situation also, like Google Music.

I have tried overriding the Service onDestroy(), onTrimMemory(), dump() methods.

public class MyForeGroundService extends Service {

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "My Service";

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    createNotificationChannel();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content Text")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Capture Started !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "createNotificationChannel()");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyForeGroundService.class));

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyForeGroundService.class);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Killed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyForeGroundService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyForeGroundService.class););
}

@Override
protected void dump(FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args) {
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyForeGroundService.class););
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But stops only when the phone cache is cleared (Clicking on Cross(X)
>   button in the Recent Apps window )

You mean when the app removed from recent apps.

> There are other application which run non-stop in this situation also.

They using their own hacks.

> Is there a way to make my foreground service run without stopping?

No, you should have your own implementation to do so.

Comment: I did not mean when the app is removed from recent apps, i mean clicking circular button at the bottom . Even if the addplication is already removed from recent apps .https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4lEj.png